# OrderBy array in AngularJS according to search

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter, angularjs-orderby

I'm still stuck with a OrderBy issue. Data comes from $http, and looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "number":1,
    "timetable": [
      {
        "name":"Station1",
        "time":"2016-05-18T18:14:00.000Z"
      },
      {
        "name":"Station2",
        "time":"2016-05-18T18:18:00.000Z"
       }
     ]
   },
   {
     "number":2,
     "timetable": [
       {
         "name":"Station1",
         "time":"2016-05-18T18:24:00.000Z"
       },
       {
         "name":"Station2",
         "time":"2016-05-18T18:28:00.000Z"
       }
     ]
   }
  ]
```

So what I need is to view rows where name is for example Station2, and I need them in order by time. The rows aren't ordered by time, nor by number. Amount of timetable rows varies, so row numbers don't help either. Is it possible to order them inside ng-repeat, in style of "OrderBy time where name='Station2' "?

EDIT:
At the moment I'm showing the results without any ordering, only with filtering. Current PHP:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in rows | limitTo:5">
  <td>
    <a href="aikataulu.php?n={{x.number}}">
      <span class="label label-primary line-{{x.lineID}}">{{x.lineID}}</span> {{x.number}}
    </a>
  </td>
  <td>
    <span ng-repeat="y in x.timetable | limitTo:-1">{{y.name}}</span> //This is for showing the destination
  </td>
  <td>
    <span ng-repeat="y in x.timetable | filter:{'name':'<?php echo $as;?>'}: true | limitTo:1">{{y.time | date:'HH:mm'}}</span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

$as is the station to be shown. So, now the order of the list comes straight from the JSON order, so it varies a lot.

Comment: You can use groupBy and orderBy on ng-repeat to deal with this. A better idea of the layout you're after would be helpful.

Comment: So i'm after a layout which would show a timetable of a station, where numbers would be arranged according to time.  
    **Station2**  
    _Number_    _Time_  
    1               18:18  
    2               18:28

Comment: Some mocked up HTML would be much better than a description. What have you done so far? It'd be nice to see the HTML and the controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [comparator](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/docs/api/ng/filter/filter) as an additional argument for the filter.

So you would expand your code to:

```
<span ng-repeat="y in x.timetable | filter:{'name':'<?php echo $as;?>'}: true : myComparator | limitTo:1">{{y.time | date:'HH:mm'}}</span>
```

You need a regexp to see if the compared string values are dates and you can do something similar to:

```
$scope.myComparator= function (a, b) {
            // regex to see if the compared values are dates
            var isDate = /(-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-)/g;

            // sorting dates
            if (isDate.test(a.value)) {
                var aDate = new Date(a.value), bDate = new Date(b.value);
                return aDate.getTime() < bDate.getTime() ? -1 : 1
            }

            // default sorting
            return a.index < b.index ? -1 : 1
        }
```

A thing worth noting is you would need a different regular expression to find your date format. Something along the lines of the following might be sufficient:

```
/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-/g
```

**NOTE:** This is untested code and serves only as a guide to the right approach. Make sure your version of AngularJS supports the comparator as a filter argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can order an array of objects by one of their properties with a filter function like this one:

```
angular.module('yourApp').filter('orderObjectBy', function() {
    return function(items, field, reverse) {
        var filtered = [];
        angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
            filtered.push(item);
        });
        filtered.sort(function (a, b) {
            return (a[field] > b[field] ? 1 : -1);
        });
        if(reverse) filtered.reverse();
            return filtered;
        };
    }
);
```

Use it like this

```
<div ng-repeat="elem in data | orderObjectBy:'number'">
    // ...
</div>
```